# grouping expressions sequence is empty

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, aggregate-functions, foundry-code-repositories

This pyspark code with **df.select** works fine.

```
def dev_prev_month(cleaned):
    df = cleaned
    
    df = df.select(
    F.coalesce(
        _sum(
            F.when(
                (F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE") > 0) &
                (
                    (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%16237890%") &
                    (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%30427132%") &
                    (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%242518801%") |
                    (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL").isNull())
                ),
                F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE")
            ).otherwise(F.lit(0))
        ),
        F.lit(0)
    ).alias("report_sum_orders_via_article")
    )
    
    return df
```

Now, I wanted to use the same logic with df.withColumn() instead of df.select().

I tried this (removed the coalesce for now):

```
def dev_prev_month(clean_joined_traffic_data):
    df = clean_joined_traffic_data
    df = df.withColumn(
        "report_sum_orders_via_article",_sum(
                F.when(
                    (F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE") > 0) &
                    (
                        (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%16237890%") &
                        (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%30427132%") &
                        (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%242518801%") |
                        (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL").isNull())
                    ),
                    F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE")
                ).otherwise(F.lit(0)))
        )
   
    return df
```

However, here I get an error that:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`!ri.foundry.main.transaction.123-123:ri.foundry.main.transaction.xxxx:master`.ORDERS' is not an aggregate function.
```

what am i missing out on?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in error you cannot use aggreagte function without groupBy. In case of select it is used implicitly, you can think about it as groupBy().agg(sum(your_condition)) so it may look like this

```
df.groupBy().agg(
    F.sum(
        F.when(
            (F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE") > 0)
            & (
                (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%16237890%")
                & (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%30427132%")
                & (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%242518801%")
                | (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL").isNull())
            ),
            F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE"),
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0))
    ).alias("report_sum_orders_via_article")
)
```

Edit: if you want to use it as withColumn you may use window function

```
windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy()

df.withColumn("report_sum_orders_via_article", F.sum(
        F.when(
            (F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE") > 0)
            & (
                (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%16237890%")
                & (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%30427132%")
                & (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL") != "%242518801%")
                | (F.col("ORDER_SUCCESS_URL").isNull())
            ),
            F.col("ORDERS_VIA_ARTICLE"),
        ).otherwise(F.lit(0))
    ).over(windowSpec))
```

With groupBy you need to join your results back to original df which of course still may be an option and may have better performance so in case of any problem my advise is to check both options

You cannot use groupBy and agg directly with "withColumn" function as it expects col and not dataframe

Comment: you're using alias here. I want to use the withColumn syntax. could you modify it accordingly?

Comment: please check my edit with possible options